# How to disable/enable usb port without software?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

My PC got crashed 2 times due to friends USBs . I want to disable the USB port so that they can't connect their USBs to my PC.I did found some softwares but I want to do it without software.

**If there is any method please share it , I am in a big problem.**

Thanks

Comment: I think a more direct and permanent answer would be to control your "*friends*" and restrict physical access to your computer.

Comment: You will find a lot of ways to do that if you google it. We can also if you tell us computer model and OS. Without that you have your answer from @Xen2050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Software follow the below steps

1. Go To Run ( Press Windows + R )
2. Type gpedit.msc in run and hit return
3. In User Configurations Click on Administrative Templates
4. System >> Removable Storage Devices
5. In the right panel double click on Removable Disks : Deny read access
6. There you will get Option for enabling or disabling any removable devices

That's it !

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique. 
http://windowsproblemsandsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/08/disable-and-enable-mass-storge-or-pen.html

Make sure before and after making changes export the registry entry.
You will have 2 registry entries. One for disable and one for enable.
Whenever you need to disable USB pen drive , just double click on disable registry file. Same thing for enabling USB pen drive.